# CORS customheaders is not working 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: javascript, c#, web-services, wcf, cors

There is a WCF webservice written in C# with two endpoints (SOAP + rest). Both services need a custom header field named "token". This custom header cannot be sent by javascript code. The response is **405 Method Not Allowed**. This is the error from the cross platform origin problem.

I have already looked for some solutions but nothing is working. I tried to fix the problem by trying out some code snipets in my localhost environment.

This is the web.config of my localhost webservice:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1"/>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>

  <system.runtime.caching>
    <memoryCache>
      <namedCaches>
        <add name="Default" physicalMemoryLimitPercentage="10" cacheMemoryLimitMegabytes="128" />
      </namedCaches>
    </memoryCache>
  </system.runtime.caching>

  <system.serviceModel>

    <services>
      <service name="MyProject.TokenTestService.Service" 
               behaviorConfiguration="ServiceAuthBehaviorHttp"
               >      
       <endpoint address=""
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBindingLocalhost"
                  contract="MyProject.TokenTestService.IService"
                  />
        <endpoint address="rest"
                  behaviorConfiguration="AjaxEnabledBehavior"
                  binding="webHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="webBindingLocalhost"
                  contract="MyProject.TokenTestService.IService"
                  />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>

      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="AjaxEnabledBehavior">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>

      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>

        <behavior name="ServiceAuthBehaviorHttp">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <TokenValidationServiceExtension ApplicationId="2" CachingTimeInSeconds="3600"  />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>

    </behaviors>

    <extensions>
      <behaviorExtensions>
        <add 
            name="TokenValidationServiceExtension" 
            type="MyProject.Authentication.Common.Extensions.TokenValidationServiceBehaviorExtension, MyProject.Authentication.Common" />
      </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>

            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IAuthServiceSoap">
              <security mode="Transport" />
            </binding>

        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IAuthServiceSoapLocalhost" />

        <binding name="BasicHttpBindingLocalhost" />

      </basicHttpBinding>

      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webBindingLocalhost" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    

    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>

    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Origin" value="localhost" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, OPTIONS" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Token, ApplicationPriviliges" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Max-Age" value="1728000" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>

  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

This is the javascript code:

```
<script>
$.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost:14305/Service.svc/rest/GetDataAdmin",
  type: "GET",
  crossDomain: true,
  dataType: 'json',
  data: null,
  headers: {
            'Content-Type':'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            'Token':'3C6E27D9-ACA7-47D9-BB8B-1C960813D79C'
  },
  success: function( result ) {
    $( "Result:" ).html( "<strong>" + result + "</strong>" );
  },
  error: function( err ) {
    $( "Result:" ).html( "<strong>" + err + "</strong>" );
  }
});
</script>
```

After requesting the services, I get my custom headers in the response (token, ApplicationPriviliges):

```
    Cache-Control: private
Allow: GET
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpcVEZTXEdJVFxMaWZiaS5BcGkuQXV0aGVudGljYXRpb24uVGVzdFNlcnZpY2VcTGlmYmkuQXBpLlRva2VuVGVzdFNlcnZpY2VcU2VydmljZS5zdmNccmVzdFxHZXREYXRhQWRtaW4=?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Origin: localhost
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Token, ApplicationPriviliges
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000
Date: Mon, 05 Feb 2018 09:48:55 GMT
Content-Length: 1766
```

The best solutions which I have found was to setup the customHeaders in the configuration of the webserver. But I doesnt work for me.

Has anyone an idea?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Possibly a red-herring.  You can get a method not allowed error when the server is actually throwing a 500 error.  Can you run the same code from the same domain you're accessing so that CORS is irrelevant?

Comment: Also, commonly I see CORS errors when authentication failed.

Comment: The function is working. I tried it by using SOAP as request (second service) and it is also working when I paste the URL into my browser. The auth extension in my code is disabeld.

Comment: Okay - thanks.  I can't help then.  My experience with CORS has been little due to it generally "just working" for me.  Good luck with your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You receive a 405 Method not allowed because your request includes the header Token which causes a Preflight request. Preflight requests use OPTIONS method, and obviously this method is not allowed by your service.

Adding customHeaders to web.config is not enough to make Preflight requests to work properly. Server must return an empty body response with a bunch of headers telling browser what is allowed.

Fortunately IIS Team has published IIS CORS module that allows you to configure CORS declaratively in web.config. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <cors enabled="true" failUnlistedOrigins="true">
            <add origin="*" />
            <add origin="https://*.microsoft.com"
                 allowCredentials="true"
                 maxAge="120"> 
                <allowHeaders allowAllRequestedHeaders="true">
                    <add header="header1" />
                    <add header="header2" />
                </allowHeaders>
                <allowMethods>
                     <add method="DELETE" />
                </allowMethods>
                <exposeHeaders>
                    <add header="header1" />
                    <add header="header2" />
                </exposeHeaders>
            </add>
            <add origin="http://*" allowed="false" />
        </cors>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

[Here](https://blogs.iis.net/iisteam/introducing-iis-cors-1-0) you have an [introduction to IIS CORS Module.](https://blogs.iis.net/iisteam/introducing-iis-cors-1-0)

You can download it form [here](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/iis-cors-module)

And [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/cors-module/cors-module-configuration-reference) is the documentation.

Unfortunately it is for the full IIS not for IIS Express. However you can configure your Visual Studio solution to work with the local IIS. You have to install it and execute Visual Studio as Administrators, but it will work.